# xpath assertionfor soap web service in jmeter

Tags: java, web-services, xpath, jmeter

I need to test using JMeter XPath, I have an response text

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:createIndexResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.example.com/">
         <example>
            <name>foer</name>
         </example>
      </ns2:createIndexResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I need to test if the name is **equal to foer**,  I used XPath assertion as `/example/name/entry[@key='name']/text()='foer'` but I get:

```
No Nodes Matched `/example/name/entry[@key='name']/text()='foer'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your example xml there is no `entry` element and no `@key` attribute. Plus the `example` element is not the root element.

try this instead for just testing the existence:

```
//example/name/text() = "foer"
```

or for selecting the `example` element:

```
//example[name/text() = "foer"]
```

Comment: I think the expression for a JMeter XPath assertion would be `//example/name/text() = "foer"`